# Why my routes are not ordered?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

in my routes file I use a route group with segment like:

```
Route::group(['prefix' =>  request()->segment(1) ], function(){
  //routes
});
```

Normally, my routes are in the order they were written at, but when using the group with `request()->segment(1)` routes just get disarranged (not just inside the group itself, but all of them), I need to use segment so every customer will have their own slug as the first segment in the URL.

so how can I fix this issue?

Comment: That looks scary. I think you could use a simple parameter instead: `Route::get('/{user}', function($user) { ... })` then `Route::get('/{user}/foo', function($user) { ... })` etc -- but I have not done that before so it might not work...

Comment: Agree with @TheManiac

Comment: But that will require updating all controllers which there are so many, I have more than a hundred routes.

Comment: submit an issue in github active contributors reply pretty fast

Comment: OK, I will do that

Answer (score 0):

Use middleware to validate the user and allow them based on their slug
Please Make own middleware like jwt.auth
I developed my own middleware to filter slug based

Comment: I have middlewares to validate users, I just need the slug to be visible in the url for each account (as this system is a Multitenant app).